# jQuery to check all by partial name

Tags: jquery

I've seen similar solutions posted that match my request, but nothing exactly as I'd like. I am very new to jQuery and do not know it well enough to figure out how to take the bits and pieces from each solution to make it work for me.

I need a function that will check all my checkboxes within my .NET grid and not the other checkboxes on the page. An example of the checkboxes that need to be checked is:

```
<input id="GridView2_ctl09_chkSelect" type="checkbox" name="GridView2$ctl09$chkSelect" />
```

I need the jQuery function to check all checkboxes with "chkSelect" at the end of the checkbox ID.

This is my current "check all" checkbox:

```
<input id="GridView2_ctl01_cbSelectAll" type="checkbox" name="GridView2$ctl01$cbSelectAll" onclick="selectAll(this);" />
```

Thanks!

Trevor

Comment: can u group the checkboxes in a wrap, say `div`?

Comment: Petr, no, because they are on a gridrow. So, I have one checkbox at beginning of row and the needed checkbox that needs to be checked at the end of row. I could wrap each checkbox in a div, but it would be a different named div for each checkbox since they're each on a different row.

Answer (score 3):

#### Description

You can use jQuery's `Attribute Contains Word Selector` to get all elements with `chkSelect` in the id attribute.

#### Sample

```
$("input[id~='chkSelect']").each(function() {
   // $(this) is a element
});
```

You can set the `checked` attribute to all your checkboxes using

```
$("input[id~='chkSelect']").attr('checked', true);
```

or

```
$("input[id~='chkSelect']").each(function() {
   // $(this) is a element
   $(this).attr('checked', true);
});
```

#### More Information

- [jQuery - Attribute Contains Word Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-word-selector/)

Comment: dknaack, what would i put in the commented section to check all my checkboxes ending in 'chkSelect'?

Comment: ? ;) If you want to check all the checkboxes ending with `chkSelect`.. check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with this ugly jQuery

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').filter(function(){
    return $(this).attr('id').substr(-9) == 'chkSelect'
}).attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Note that far more convenient is to wrap the relevant inputs in a div and target it

```
$('div.targetdiv input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Svpq4/1/

```
$('input[id$=SelectAll]').click(function(){
    if(!$('input[id$=chkSelect]').is(':checked'))
    $('input[id$=chkSelect]').attr('checked', 'checked')
    else
    $('input[id$=chkSelect]').removeAttr('checked')
});
```

is this what you are after?

Comment: this does not work. unless i'm supposed to wrap it inside some other function.

Comment: sorry, i didn't put it in the document ready function. your function works for me now! although, I was hoping I could do it with less lines of code. but it works!